# Inline css clip-path not respected on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip-path

I am making some animation and graphics libraries to work with html. For some things clipping is needed and since the elements are generated dynamically, [`clip-path` (mostly `polygon`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) is added dynamicaly in elements'a style property :

`el.style.clipPath = 'polygon(..)';`

Firefox (76) works just fine, however Chrome (83) (and Opera as well) dont respect the `clip-path` property (on chrome element inspect it is not even shown on element's style properties as present)

It was supposed to be a bug in Chrome prior to v.64 but wherever I looked it says latest chrome (and webkit browsers in general) have full support for `clip-path` and `polygon` in particular.

**Note:** It is not an issue to test with url of `svg` path to be used a clip mask, but I would like to avoid `svg`, I would like to keep it pure `html/css` (*however if i rememeber correctly not even `svg` inline url works with chrome when I was pulling my hair trying to figure out why it doesnt work as expected*).

I have also tried adding with browser prefix (ie `el.style.WebkitClipPath = 'polygon(..)'`) but nothing changed.

Test example should display a triangle (doesnt work on Chrome, at least my latest Chrome 83.0.4103.61 64bit windows):

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.style.clipPath = 'border-box polygon(0px 0px, 200px 100px, 0px 200px)';
```

```css
#test{
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: #ff0000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #00ff00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

What am I missing? Does chrome support `clip-path` with `polygon`, or not?

Comment: share the code .

Comment: @TemaniAfif added test example. See it on chrome, at least it doesnt work on mine

Comment: remove border-box, it's not needed

Comment: Are you saying that this is the problem? Because according to spec this is supposd to work, and border-box IS needed for my case

Comment: what do you expect when using border-box? you have no border, no padding, no margin, so it's not needed

Comment: @TemaniAfif, indeed if i remove border-box it works on chrome, but this is a bug, isnt it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif My use case has elements WITH borders and I want to clip with borders

Comment: share your full use case then ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Updated. The case is simply elements with border and `box-sizing` of `border-box`. If `border-box` is removed from `clipPath` then it works, but the spec says otherwise, in any case a box model is assumed when applying `clip-path` and I want to make it explicit. So this is a chrome bug as I see it.

Comment: even if you set the property using CSS it won't work. Either a bug or something has changed in the Spec

Comment: @TemaniAfif, indeed it doesnt work either way (have tried all ways), if a box-model (what is called `geometry-box`) is added to clip-path. But this is a missing feature that the spec according to latest MDN supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To sum up the comments by [@TemaniAfif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) in an answer so it stays:*

If `border-box` is removed from `clip-path`, eg:

`test.style.clipPath = 'polygon(..)';`

then it works in Chrome too. However as per the [latest spec on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), the following is valid combination and should be supported (support for Chrome on that page is green as grass):

> ```
> /* Box and shape values combined */
> clip-path: padding-box circle(50px at 0 100px);
> ```

The `clip-path` assumes a box model anyway, and it is imperative in certain cases that user sets the assumed box-model, for clipping, explicitly, so that is why combined values are supported. But it seems it is not so for Chrome (and Opera as far as I have tested).

So this is only a workaround untill full support of the feature is provided.